# Lotus Notes: how can i extract number in a specific position after comma

Tags: lotus-notes

Il lotus notes 6.5 i have some numeric field set to show only 2 number after comme (ex 2,25) but sometimes the complete number is for ex. 2,25387.
How can i check via lotus notes script how many decimals have a numeber ?
after that, how can i extract the numbers in a specific position or range ?

For example:

```
in the field i see: 2,25 
the whole number is: 2,25387
using lotus notes script want to extract third and fourth number after comma, in this case 38.
```

**how can i do this ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use getitemvalue...

```vb
Dim doc as NotesDocument
Dim dblNumber as Double

Set doc = .... '- Somehow get the document
dblNumber = doc.GetItemValue( "NameOfNumericField" )(0)
```

To get the doc:

In an agent that runs on selected documents:

```vb
Dim ses as New NotesSession
Dim db as NotesDatabase
Dim dc as NotesDocumentCollection
Dim doc as NotesDocument

Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase
Set dc = db.UnprocessedDocuments
Set doc = dc.GetFirstDocument
```

In a button called from an open document:

```vb
Dim ws as New NotesUIWorkspace
Set doc = ws.CurrentDocument.Document
```

in dblValue you have the complete number. Use basic math to get the third and fourth digit after comma.